# Reference request: Recreational Mathematics and Inequalities

Tags: inequality, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I am interested in finding out more information on references regarding recreational mathematics, specifically when working with inequalities. I enjoy working on problems from http://awesomemath.org under **Mathematical Reflections**. Many of the problems deal with proving that the following inequality holds, for example:

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^3}} \leq 1$. Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq 12$ (from **Mathematical Reflections -Issue 3 2017**).

Upon looking at some of the older solutions, many solutions use the AM-GM inequality or other neat tricks involving rewriting the expression or a substitution.

I do not have a strong background regarding these types of problems. I am hoping to find references that will help me with working on these types of questions-books, articles, similar questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Putnam and Beyond by Titu Andreescu! http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lototsky/PiMuEp/PutnamAndBeyond-Andreescu.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this article is helping me very much! +1 and accepted.